# Angular momentum without an axis of rotation?

Tags: classical-mechanics

A rigid body consists of particles of masses $m_i$ at distances $r_i$ from the origin, having linear momentum $p_i$. My teacher defined $∑r_i×p_i$ as simply the angular momentum of the system. But in case of rotation of a body about an axis, he defined the exact same thing but called it the "angular momentum of the body *about* the axis of rotation". Why is that?

Comment: A system, such as $\sum r_i\times p_i$, can have multiple axes.

Answer (score 1):

When you write $\sum r_i\times p_i$ you're implicitly depending on an origin point somewhere in space, from which you're measuring the $r_i$s.

So you're speaking about angular momentum *about that point*.

In the case of a rigid rotation it turns out that it doesn't matter which point *on the axis of rotation* you're using as the origin, so in that case you can just ask for angular momentum about the entire axis.